# よう - Nayou & Noyou

Tags: particle-の, particle-な

For よう, why do we prepend な for Na-adjectives, and の for regular nouns?  Is there a logical understanding behind this from like a Japanese perspective?  I feel as though since they're both technically nouns, then we should treat them the same.

Comment: Your question is unclear -- when you say, _"they're both technically nouns"_, what does "both" refer to here?

Comment: Separately, please understand that particles in Japanese do not prepend anything -- particles are added after the word or phrase that they mark.

Comment: By both, I mean Na-adjectives and Nouns are both technically nouns.  So why do we use a na for one and no for the rest?

Comment: Ah, no, _-na_ adjectives are not technically nouns.  _Some_ of the _-na_ adjectives are _also_ nouns, but as a general class of words, _-na_ adjectives are not nouns.  [This question and answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/91178/how-to-tell-when-a-na-adjective-is-being-used-as-a-noun-as-opposed-to-an-adject) discusses this a bit, with examples of two _-na_ adjectives that cannot be used as nouns, and one _-na_ adjective that can also be used as a noun.

Comment: It seems like the question reduces to why are some words na adjectives and others nouns.

Comment: This might be a little overkill for the question, but maybe it would also be kind of useful to address 連体形 here? Since all the things you can put before a na-adj/noun such as よう is a 連体形, as long as you want to see の as a possible 連体形 of nouns.

Answer (score 1):

よう is basically a na-adjective which can also behave as a noun.

Note that not all na-adjectives can be used as nouns, but some can. That's why they fall under the category of adjectival nouns: no-adjectives and na-adjectives, using の and な respectively.

---

### よう as a noun

After **nouns** + no:

- 彼は**留守**のようでした。

After **adjectival** nouns + na/no in the non-past affirmative context:

- 彼は**大丈夫**なようです。 大丈夫 is a na-adjective, which is modifying よう, a noun.
- 彼は**病気**のようだ。病気 is a no-adjective, which is modifying よう, a noun.

After **adjectival** nouns or **nouns** + じゃない, だった or じゃなかった in the past context:

- 彼は練習が**嫌**だったようです。The clause 彼は練習が嫌だった modifies よう, a noun.

### よう as a na-adjective

Once よう has been modified, this noun can also modify another noun. To do this, な is used.

- この間食べたようなケーキだよ。この間食べた modifies よう, and よう modifies ケーキ by using な.

Just like a na-adjective, it can be followed by に to form an adverb.

- 彼女はまるで魚のように速く泳げます。魚 modifies よう, and ように creates an adverb to modify 速く泳げます.